# Function is getting undefined parameter Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm working with an application that uses Mongo as DB and node.js. I created a function which is meant to recieve a parameter named *orderedBy* but my console.log, prints an undefined parameter. Why is this happening? Here's the code.

```
exports.showAll = function(orderedBy, callback){

var query = {orderedBy: orderedBy}
console.log("Orderer by ===== "+ orderedBy);

var array = models.Orden.find(query).lean().exec(function(err, orders) {
    if( orders.length > 0) {
        callback({'array' : orders});
        //callback({'array' : JSON.stringify(orders)});
    }
    else {
        callback({'error' : "You don't have any orders"});
    }
});}
```

And here i call showAll

```
app.post('/api/showAll', function(req, res) {
      var orderedBy = req.body.orderedBy;
      ordenes.showAll(orderedBy, function(found){
           console.log(found);
           res.json(found);
      });
 });
```

Basically, what I want is get an ID and show how many orders that person has. But my response is always "You don't have any orders" mainly because me console log, shows that orderedBy is undefined.

And yes i'm making sure i'm sending the correct ID, simulating it with Postman

Comment: Show code where you call `showAll`

Comment: added I forgot that might be needed

Comment: add `console.log(orderedBy)`, in router to be sure that body contains that parameter.

Comment: To get `req.body.orderedBy` you generally need a bodyParser

Comment: @AlexanderMac thanks, this helped me find the problem, thought it was my function but it was my route. I was stupidly sending form-data, instead of x-www-form-urlencoded in post man.  

It was never broken, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

your `req` request object have two properties called

- body: when you send a POST/PUT request will be populate by the body of the request
- query: when you send a request, (no matters the method) will be populate by the queryString. example http://localhost:3000?orderBy=AAAA

  on your server side you can can `req.orderBy === 'AAAA'`

Answer (score 0):

Thought it was my function being wrong, but it was my parameters. I was stupidly sending form-data, instead of x-www-form-urlencoded in postman. It was never broken, thanks.